# Trying to render a cube using index buffer Qt OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am writing a simple Qt5.5 project where I am trying to render a colored cube using `QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer`.

The problem is that nothing appears on the screen (only the background).
The source code is uploaded to https://github.com/lorda666/GLCube. I am not sure if the matrices are set up correctly or something else is the problem.

I can't find too much info on how to use index buffers in Qt, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: When you translate the cube by `320.0f, 240.0f, 0.0f` it will most probably be out of view. And even if not, since you are at Z=2 and the cube goes from z=-10 to z=10, you would be inside the cube.

Comment: And just for completeness: Questions seeking for debugging help have to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for the critique and I apologize, Indeed the translation was the problem(there were other problems as well). I thought that `(320.0f, 240.0f, 0.0f)` will be the center of the screen (screen size: 640 x 480), but actually `(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` is. Thank you.